# how to get the array element which has a maximum length in the given array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to get the array element which has maximum length in the given array.

Suppose there is an array:

```
const a = ["apple","banana","mango","watermelon","grapes"];
```

Here I need to get `watermelon` as output because `watermelon` has the maximum length.

Below is what has been tried

```
let length7=0;
let maxlength = function fn() {
  for (i7=0; i7<a.length; i7++) {
    if (a[i7].length > length7) {
      length7=a[i7].length
    }
  };
  return length7;
};
console.log(maxlength())
```

From this I am getting the length of the maximum string(as 10). But I need to get the output as `watermelon`.

Please explain an optimal solution to the problem.

Comment: Instead of saving the length in the variable, save the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the longest element in a seperate variable and return that.

```js
let maxlength = function fn() {

  let length7 = 0;
  let value = "";
  
  for (i7 = 0; i7 < a.length; i7++) {

    if (a[i7].length > length7) {

      length7 = a[i7].length;
      value = a[i7];

    }

  }
  return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below solution may be one possible solution to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const getLongestWordIn = arr => (
  arr.reduce(
    (acc, word) => (word.length > acc.length ? word : acc),
    ""
  )
);

const a = ["apple","banana","mango","watermelon","grapes"];

console.log(getLongestWordIn(a));
```

**Explanation**

- Use `.reduce` to iterate over the array
- The aggregator/accumulator named `acc` is initialized as empty string `""`
- If the word (being iterated) has length more than `acc`, then assign that word to `acc`
- Else, simply return `acc`

Answer (score 0):

You need to store either (1) just the element with the maximum length or (2) both the element and it's maximum length. You should also move the current `max` variable (`max7` in your case) inside the function. Putting this together and opting for (2):

```js
function longestElement(arr) {
  if (!arr.length) return; // empty array
  let longest = arr[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
    longest = arr[i].length > longest.length ? arr[i] : longest;
  return longest;
}
let a=["apple","banana","mango","watermelon","grapes"];
console.log(longestElement(a)); // "watermelon"
```

If you want to shorten this, you can use `reduce`:

```js
const longestElement = (arr) => arr.reduce((x, y) => x.length > y.length ? x : y);
```

Comment: `![]` is `false`.

Comment: @Unmitigated fixed, must be `arr.length`

Comment: What does ? does in the above code. And can you please explain the code

Comment: Saiteja: That's a ternary - `x = cond ? a : b` is basically a shorter way of writing an `let x; if (cond) x = a else x = b`

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to save the index of the maximum length of the array.
Easiest way is to save the index (i7) in a global variable. Then at the end of the iterations instead of saving the maximum length you will have the index of the item with the maximum lenght. Then you just access it from the array.
An examen of the code:

```
let maxLengthIndex=0

let maxlength=function fn(){

  for(i7=0 ; i7<a.length ; i7++){

    if(a[i7].length > a[maxLengthIndex].length){

      maxLengthIndex = i7
    }
  }
  return a[maxLengthIndex]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the longest string on each iteration and replace it by the next element in the array if it's longer.

```js
const array = ["apple", "banana", "mango", "watermelon", "grapes"];
let longestStr = '';
array.forEach((str) => {
    if (str.length > longestStr.length) {
        longestStr = str;
    }
});
console.log(longestStr);
```

You can also use reduce function on arrays to return the longest. [Documentation for array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const longestStr = array.reduce((prev, current) => current.length > prev.length ? current : prev, '');
```